# Connecting line from one svg shape to other svg shapes when clicked using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, dom-events

I'm trying to connect two svg shapes using a line.  When the svg rect that is blue is clicked it gets initial start position for the line. The second shape that is clicked that is also blue gets final position. How can I draw this data to the path so I can connect the two rects?  Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var init_x;
var init_y;
var nextClick = false;

function myFunction(clicked_id) {
  const svg = d3.selectAll('svg');
  const num_g_children = svg.node().children.length;
  const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform',`translate(0,${num_g_children*35})`);

  g.append('rect')
    .attr('id','node_block_' + clicked_id)
    .attr('x',50)
    .attr('y',20)
    .attr('rx',20)
    .attr('ry',20)
    .attr('width',145)
    .attr('height',95)
    .attr('transform','translate(0,-15)')
    .attr('style','fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;cursor:grab;');

  g.append('rect')
    .text('node_output')
    .attr('id','node_output_' + clicked_id)
    .attr('width',10)
    .attr('height',10)
    .attr('transform','translate(50,49)')
    .attr('style','cursor:pointer;fill:blue;stroke-width:3;stroke:black;')
    .on('click',setLine);
    
  var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
      });
  d3.selectAll('g').datum({x: 0, y: 0}).call(dragcontainer);
  }
function setLine(){
  var g = d3.selectAll('svg').select('g'); 
  if(nextClick == false)
  {
    init_x = d3.event.x;
    init_y = d3.event.y;
    nextClick = true;
  }
  else
  {
    var final_x = d3.event.x;
    var final_y = d3.event.y;
    var linesData = [{x: init_x,y: init_y},{x: final_x,y: final_y}];
    var lines = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    g.append('path')
      .attr('id','line_' + this.id)
      .attr('d',lines(linesData)) 
      .attr('style','cursor:pointer;stroke-width:6;stroke:green;');

    nextClick = false;
    }
  }
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
}
svg {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a class="btn-small" id="rectA" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">A</a>
  <a class="btn-small " id="rectB" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">B</a>
</div>
<svg class="myViewbox" id="viewBoxId" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Don't use `onclick=...`, use normal JS-side `addEventListener` on your buttons. Which don't need a `type` _unless_ they're inside a form, which wouldn't make a lot of sense in this case =) So, with that said: please turn this into a snippet that folks can run, and clean up the indent etc a bit so that people you want help from can easily read the code you're dealing with.

Comment: First time doing snippets. I hope this helps.

Comment: don't put the snippet in code blocks =) Also please look at your post after updating instead of trusting "things are fine": there's clearly still a lot of wonky indentation going on, so please still edit that into something easy to read for folks who want to help you. And finally, remember to also _test_ the code you're posting, because any kind of reducing or [mcve] might no longer do what your own code does. For example, this code throws an error the moment you click on a blue rect. That's probably not what you meant.

Comment: The indents were all wonky from copying my code and pasting it in.  Fixed most of them and edited the code again seeing how I was trying to set init_x of an attribute that was undefined which fixed the error of clicking on the box the first time. Next tested it with just a line svg and get 2 lines when the 2 buttons are clicked.  If I add an offset it will fix this resulting diagonal line displayed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can any one give an example how to do this with link?

Answer (score 0):

This was specifically what I was looking for took a while to find this library. Works like a charm!  If anybody else has trouble with this I hope this helps.

```js
var start_id;
var nextClick = false;
  
function myFunction(clicked_id) {
  const svg = d3.selectAll('svg');
  const num_g_children = svg.node().children.length;
  const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform',`translate(0,${num_g_children*35})`);

  g.append('rect')
   .attr('id','node_block_' + clicked_id)
   .attr('x',50)
   .attr('y',20)
   .attr('rx',20)
   .attr('ry',20)
   .attr('width',145)
   .attr('height',95)
   .attr('transform','translate(0,-15)')
   .attr('style','fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;cursor:grab;');

  g.append('rect')
   .text('node_output')
   .attr('id','node_output_' + clicked_id)
   .attr('width',10)
   .attr('height',10)
   .attr('transform','translate(50,49)')
   .attr('style','cursor:pointer;fill:blue;stroke-width:3;stroke:black;')
   .on('click',setLine);
        
  var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
        .on("drag", function(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
          });
      d3.selectAll('g').datum({x: 0, y: 0}).call(dragcontainer);
      }
function setLine(){
  var g = d3.selectAll('svg').select('g'); 
  if(nextClick == false){
     start_id = this.id;
     nextClick = true;
  }
  else{
     var end_id = this.id;
     new LeaderLine(document.getElementById(start_id),
                    document.getElementById(end_id),             {startPlug:"square",endPlug:"square",startPlugSize:.4,endPlugSize:.4,color:"blue", size: 6});
     nextClick = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.5/leader-line.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn-small" id="rectA" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">A</a>
      <a class="btn-small " id="rectB" onclick="myFunction(this.id);">B</a>
    </div>
    <svg class="myViewbox" id="viewBoxId" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```